# Android Custom TabBar

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have seen a couple of application having a TabBar like the following [here](http://cdn.vikitech.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Music02.png). I am talking about the widget the bottom left hand corner of the image. You can drag the circular disc and change the tab. Also an Image POP ups about the current TAB. I have tried searching about but so far no luck.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that HTC developed for their own usage.

it is not available openly to developers sorry.

If you want something like this you will need to develop it on your own. 
You can achieve this by using a TabHost widget with TabWidget placed in a horizontal scroll view and then on tab click show some kind of custom fullscreen Toast message with the description and the image. also customize the TabWidget, you can definitely find info on the Tabhost and customizing the tabwidget either here on stackoverflow or some tutorials on google.

In any case you definitely need to do this from scratch, but its certainly possible.

Comment: Too Bad. I was really looking forward to adding it to my application.